# NetCDF format to vector tiles

Tags: netcdf, vector-tiles, mapbox-vector-tile

I am new to GIS area.
Currently, I have NetCDF file and want to convert it to Vector Tiles.
I tried to use GeoServer extension for this, but it has limited flexibility on what I want.
I have come across Mapbox Vector Tiles (mvt) but do not know how I can convert NetCDF to MVT. Is it possible and how?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: NetCDF are usually raster files and so it doesn't really make sense to convert them to vector tiles